# Como fazer o hibernate ler uma tabela em um banco MySQL e gravar em uma outra tabela no PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Preciso consultar um banco no MySQL e pegar uma tabela de lá para gravar em um banco no PostgreSQL pelo Hibernate/JPA.

Configurei o `persistence.xml` da seguinte forma:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="postgreSQL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tfProjeto" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />


        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="mySQL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/meuProjeto?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

E minha EntityFactory está assim:

```
@RequestScoped
public class EntityFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryMySQL;

    public static void initializeEntityManager() {
        if ((entityManagerFactory == null) || (!entityManagerFactory.isOpen())) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgreSQL");
        }
    }

    public static void initializeEntityManagerMySql() {
        if ((entityManagerFactoryMySQL == null) || (!entityManagerFactoryMySQL.isOpen())) {
            entityManagerFactoryMySQL = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mySQL");
        }
    }

}
```

Porém, quando gero as classes, o Hibernate cria em ambos os bancos as duas tabelas. Ou seja, preciso pegar da `users`(MySQL) e gravar em `usuarios`(PostgreSQL), porém o Hibernate cria as tabelas `users` e `usuarios` no MySQL e as tabelas users e `usuarios` no PostgreSQL também, e o que quero é apenas criar a `usuarios` apenas na base do PostgreSQL.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Não entendi direito seu problema: você não quer que gere as tabelas nas duas bases e além disto não está conseguindo fazer as consultas, é isso? Ou apenas a geração nas bases que está errada? Por que mesmo gerando as tabelas em ambas bases, se vocês usar a EM correta irá salvar os dados no outro. Ou seja: usando EM do MySQL para ler `users` vai recuperar os dados de lá, trata conforme tu precisa e salva em `usuarios` usando a EM do PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por padrão o Hibernate vai procurar entidades que estejam no mesmo *classpath* do `persitence.xml`, ou seja, entidades que esteja no mesmo jar. Como ele faz isto é o comportamento esperado o que está acontecendo contigo, ou seja, ele irá mesmo criar nas duas bases. Veja aqui: [ressalvas](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_caveats). Está no tópico de OSGi, mas o comportamento é o mesmo.

Para alterar este comportamento você tem que dar um jeito de dizer ao Hibernate não criar as tabelas de tudo que ele vê pela frente, ou fazer com que ele não tenha conhecimento das entidades que você não quer. Há diversas forma de fazer isto, alguns dependendo dos frameworks que você está usando (no Spring é bem simples de configurar quais pacotes a serem escaneados ou ter filtros), seguem duas:

- listar as entidades em cada unidade de persistência que você quer que o Hibernate gerencie e dizer a ele para excluir as que não estão listadas, além de listar as que serão gerenciadas por cada unidade de persistência. Ficará algo assim:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="postgreSQL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <class>com.model.Usuario</class>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="mySQL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <class>com.model.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

- separar as entidades de cada unidade de persistência em um projeto/jar. Como por padrão serão lidas as entidades do projeto, separando em outros artefatos você evita que ele tenha conhecimento, algo assim:

  - **projeto-user**: contém a entidade `com.model.User`, com seu respectivo `persistence.xml` com apenas uma unidade de persistência.
  - **projeto-usuario**: contém a entidade `com.model.Usuario`, com seu respectivo `persistence.xml` com apenas uma unidade de persistência.

Eu particularmente prefiro esta segunda abordagem na maioria dos casos que precisei trabalhar com diversas unidades de persistência, torna mais simples evoluir, você não precisa sempre ter que configurar as entidades nas unidades de persistência, mas gera um pequeno *overhead* para gerenciar estes pacotes a mais, principalmente se existir coisas comuns nas duas unidades de persistência (neste caso você pode configurar `<jar-file>`, enfim).

Isto fará com que não existam tabelas desnecessárias nas bases, mas não garante que irá funcionar a migração, visto que você é que deve garantir que está trabalhando com o `EntityManager` correto. Ou seja, como exemplo, vamos assumir que iremos pegar os dados do MySQL e inserir no PostgreSQL, ficaria algo assim:

```
EntityFactory.initializeEntityManager();
EntityFactory.initializeEntityManagerMySql();

final EntityManager emMySQL = EntityFactory.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
final EntityManager emPostgreSQL = EntityFactory.entityManagerFactoryMySQL.createEntityManager();

final List<User> users = emMySQL.createQuery("SELECT u FROM com.model.User u");

final List<Usuario> usuarios = /* converte users para usuarios */;

// faça o tratamento conforme sua necessidade
usuarios.forEach(u -> emPostgreSQL./* atualiza/cria o usuário */);

// continua com o que tem que fazer :)
```